# Can't follow links when web-scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I realize that others have covered similar topics, but having read these posts, I still can't solve my problem.

I am using Scrapy to write a crawl spider that should scrape search results pages. One example could be the results for all the 1 bed room apartments in the bay area on CraigsList.org. They are found here:

http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/apa?zoomToPosting=&query=&srchType=A&minAsk=&maxAsk=&bedrooms=1

This shows the first 100 1-bedroom apartments in the Bay area. The 201st to 300th apartments are on this page

http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/apa?bedrooms=1&srchType=A&s=100

And for the next 100 "&s=100" will be changed to "&s=200" etc. Let's say I want the name of the first post on each of these pages with results. I know it isn't very meaningful, but it's just to have a simple example.

My problem is how to write the rule so that "&s=100" is incremented to "&s=200" etc. This is what I have:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Torrent(Item):
    name = Field()

class MySpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'MySpider'
    allowed_domains = ['http://sfbay.craigslist.org']
    start_urls = ['http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/apa?zoomToPosting=&query=&srchType=A&minAsk=&maxAsk=&bedrooms=1']
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'&s=\d+']), 'parse_torrent', follow=True)]

    def parse_torrent(self, response):
        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        torrent = Torrent()
        torrent['name'] = x.select("id('toc_rows')/p[2]/span[1]/a/text()").extract()
        return torrent
```

Can anyone set my rule straight, so that I get the name of the first post for each of the result pages?

Thanks!

Comment: you should post the error message

Comment: @bwbrowning: Okay, Just thought it would be too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis that you're simply pulling information out of each index page, you could just generate a list of appropriate start urls and then use a BaseSpider instead. No rules required and it's a lot simpler to use.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Torrent(Item):
    name = Field()

class MySpiderSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'MySpider'
    allowed_domains = ['http://sfbay.craigslist.org']
    start_urls = ['http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/apa?bedrooms=1&srchType=A&s=%d' %n for n in xrange(0, 2500, 100)]

    def parse(self, response):
        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        torrent = Torrent()
        torrent['name'] = x.select("id('toc_rows')/p[2]/span[1]/a/text()").extract()
        return torrent
```

Comment: Thanks, that will do it! And I especially like the simplicity of not needing to use rules. I'm curios if there is an easy way to iterate the number of pages, `n`, without having to know the maximum number of pages (2500)?

Comment: Here's a previous answer I gave which has an initial parse function to determine the number of pages and then yields requests for each of those additional pages:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417512/how-do-i-create-rules-for-a-crawlspider-using-scrapy/14420643